# Null Reference exception while pushpin Tap in bing maps in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

I am displaying the pushpin in a map.

```
 void GeoPositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            _pushpins.Clear();
            var cor = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);
            //Using the current coordinates define the Map center to those coordinates.
            map.Center = cor;
            _pushpins.Add(new PushpinModel
            {

                Description = "test",
                Name = "test",
                Location = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude,
                                                e.Position.Location.Longitude),
                DatetimeAdded = DateTime.Now
            });

            map.ZoomLevel = 15;


        }
```

For pushpin loading taking some time because the pushpin is moving to current location in a map.in that time whenever click on pushpin giving "NULL Reference Exception".please tell me how to handle that?

EDIT:

```
 private void Pushpin_Tap(object sender,
        System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            var _ppmodel = sender as Pushpin;
            Pushpin pin = sender as Pushpin;

             _id = _ppmodel.Tag.ToString();

            ContextMenu contextMenu =
                ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(_ppmodel);

            contextMenu.DataContext = _pushpins.Where
                (c => (c.Location
                    == _ppmodel.Location)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (contextMenu.Parent == null)
            {
                contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }
```

While pushpin tap some times getting null reference exception........

Comment: How can the exception be recreated? The code in your question is not for the tap event. How is it relevant?

Comment: Why getting the some times null reference exception.can u please check my edit code once....

Comment: Where are you setting up the event handler? I suspect you're getting tap events from senders other than a Pushpin, which will cause a NullReferenceException when trying to read the Tag property

Comment: Where can i write the pushpin tap event handler?please let me know..